# Hyperref and finding the correct reference

Tags: hyperref

I am using the `hyperref` package to make hyperlinks in a PDF document. Sometimes the targets aren't clear because there is a lot of information on each page.

Is there a way to make the hyperlink do something additional that will make the target more obvious? For example, MiKTeX's sync feature shades part of the text yellow for a few seconds. I'd like to build this in to my hyperlinks.

Comment: Acording to the manual you should be able to use anchorcolor with \hypertarget, but I have not been able to get it to work.